# What's the trace distance between $|0\rangle^{\otimes n}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|0\rangle^{\otimes n} + |1 \rangle^{\otimes n} \big)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace-distance

I'm trying to figure out the trace distance between the states
$\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$, where
$$
\begin{align}\rho_1 &= (|0\rangle \langle 0|)^{\otimes n}\,,\\
\rho_2 &= \dfrac{1}{2}(|0\rangle^{\otimes n}  + |1 \rangle^{\otimes n}) (\langle 0|^{\otimes n}  + \langle 1 |^{\otimes n})\,. 
\end{align}$$

However, I am not sure how to proceed.

I know that we can calculate the trace distance using the sum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $\rho_1-\rho_2$, but it is not at all obvious what that is to me.

Answer (score 3):

Writing $|b^n\rangle := |b\rangle^{\otimes n}$ for $b \in \{0,1\}$, we have
\begin{equation}
\rho_2 - \rho_1 = \frac{1}{2}|0^n\rangle \langle 0^n| - \frac{1}{2}|0^n\rangle \langle 1^n| - \frac{1}{2}|1^n\rangle \langle 0^n| -\frac{1}{2}|1^n\rangle \langle 1^n| \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Regardless of the value of $n$, this matrix basically looks the same: It is a $2^n\times 2^n$ matrix with a $1/2$ in the top left corner, and $-1/2$ in the other three corners. Since this matrix only acts nontrivially on a $2$-dimensional subspace spanned by the elements in Eq. (1), it will only have two nonzero eigenvalues. These eigenvalues are computed from the matrix
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c}
\leftarrow|0^n\rangle  \\ \leftarrow|1^n\rangle
\end{array} \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where the kets with the arrows identify the subspace  $\text{span}(|0^n\rangle, |1^n\rangle)$ of our Hilbert space in which we know the eigenvectors must live (not that this is relevant for computing the eigenvalues).

I don't see an "easy way" to get the eigenvalues of Eq. (2), but you can now either solve for them by hand or use computer software (Wolfram Alpha), and the trace distance will follow immediately.

Comment: ... regarding the eigenvalues, this is more or less the Hadamard matrix, up to a minus sign, so $\pm1/\sqrt{2}$.